# if else with multiple conditions combined with AND and OR

Tags: r

I am looking for a way to create a new variable (1,0) with 1 for multiple conditions combined with AND and OR.

i.e. if

a > 3 AND b > 5

OR

c > 3 AND d > 5

OR

e > 3 AND f > 5

1

if not

0

I've tried coding it as;

```
df$newvar <- ifelse(df$a > 3 & df$b > 5 | df$c > 3 & df$d > 5 | df$e > 3 & df$f > 5,"1","0")
```

But in my output many variables are coded as NA and the numbers do not seem to add up.

Does anyone have advice on a proper way to code this?

Comment: If you have NA in your columns, use `& is.na(df$a)` etc

Answer (score 0):

We can subset the columns to evaluate for values greater than 3, get a `list` of logical `vector`s ('l1'), similarly for values greater than 5 ('l2'), then compare the corresponding elements of `list` using `Map` and `Reduce` it to a single `vector`.  With `as.integer`, we coerce the logical vector to binary

```
l1 <- lapply(df[c('a', 'c', 'e')] , function(x) x > 3 & !is.na(x))
l2 <- lapply(df[c('b', 'd', 'f')], function(x) x > 5 & !is.na(x))
df$newvar <- as.integer(Reduce(`|`, Map(`&`, l1, l2)))
df$newvar
#[1] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0
```

---

Or using the OP's method

```
with(df, as.integer((a >3 & !is.na(a) & b > 5 & !is.na(b)) | (c > 3 & !is.na(c) &
        d > 5 & !is.na(d)) | (e > 3 & !is.na(e) & f > 5 & !is.na(f))))
#[1] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:8), 6 * 10, replace = TRUE), 
                ncol = 6, dimnames = list(NULL, letters[1:6])))
```